# Configuring Lambda with SNSEvent *and* creating a Subscription with Protocol: lambda results in just one Subscription, but which?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-sam

If you configure a Lambda with `SNSEvent` this creates a subscription.

If you configure a Subscription with a `Protocol: lambda`  this also creates a subscription.

When you configure **both**, (with the exact same endpoints) you only get one subscription. Do both get merged, does one overwrite the other, what exactly is going on?

I'm asking to get a better understanding of CloudFormation.

For example:

```yaml
# ReceivedRequestSNS Role
   ReceivedRequestsSNS:
     Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
     Properties:
       TopicName: !Sub
         - ${StackName}-ReceivedRequests-${Stage}
         - StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
           Stage: !Ref Stage 

   ReceivedRequestsToLambdaSuscription:
     Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
     Properties:
       Protocol: lambda
       Endpoint: !Sub
         - ${LambdaArn}:live
         - { LambdaArn: !GetAtt TrainingNotificationsRequestsHandler.Arn }
       RedrivePolicy:
         deadLetterTargetArn : !GetAtt ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQ.Arn
       TopicArn: !Ref ReceivedRequestsSNS

   TrainingNotificationsRequestsHandler:
     Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
     Properties:
       Handler: 'com.test.handlers.RequestsHandler::handleRequest'
       Runtime: java8
       Events:
         SNSEvent:
           Type: SNS 
           Properties:
             Topic: !Ref ReceivedRequestsSNS
```

Comment: Serverless will produce final yaml file. It should be in your deployment bucket. You can inspect it, or post here, to check what exactly is happening and what is the final form of the CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 0):

The [SAM Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-sns.html) states that:

> SAM generates AWS::SNS::Subscription resource when this event type is set

I would use either the SAM SNS Event Source, or the "raw" `AWS:SNS::Subscription`, but not both.  Any behavior when both are specified seems undocumented and should not be relied on.